# Paragraphs to indexcards

Tags: numbering, paragraphs, flashcards

I am new to this community. I have been using latex since 2012, but, as a humanties person, I am not well-acquainted with the page layout in Latex. I basically used templates for everything I did. For what I want now, there is no template that I am aware of.

I want to go through all of my draft text (about 200k words) for the book that I am writing and I have received advice about physically cutting and arranging my writing. One thing that I do want to do is to *print out each paragraph, preferably numbered, on a separate sheet (large indexcard size would be great)* and work with it physically in the last stage. Physical cut and paste would be a problem because I would lose the footnotes. I think this would be a piece of cake for some people on this forum. I would appreciate any help.

Harun

Comment: I'd think something like the [`geometry` package](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) with `paper=a6paper` (slightly larger than an index card). You may need to modify the margin size...perhaps the easiest way is to `\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}`.